# what condition should i use in while loop?

Tags: c

My aim here is to copy string1 into string2 in reversed order, however my condition in the second while loop is obviously incorrect, how do i implement the while loop to continue until all the letters from string1 have entered string2?since the '\0' in string1 has already passed after decrementing pointer1 before while loop ...

```
//reversing strings.. 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *pointer1;
    char *pointer2;
    char string1[20];
    char string2[20];
    pointer1 = string1; //allowing pointer to point to first letter of string1
    pointer2 = string2; //allowing pointer2 to point to first alphabet of string2
    printf("enter a string\n");
    gets(string1);
    while (*pointer1)
    {pointer1++;}
    pointer1--;
    while(*pointer2)
    {
        *pointer2 = *pointer1;
        pointer1--;
        pointer2++; 
    }
    *pointer2 = '\0';
    printf("%s", string2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If humans indent their codes, the world would have been different.

Comment: i dont understand, why are you trying to reverse a string in a method that returns an `int`.

Comment: hehe sorry, i didnt have time, got an exam tom

Comment: `while(*pointer2)` -> `while(pointer1>=string1)`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY it worked but by using the relational operator with pointers, ur comparing the size of the pointers or what?

Comment: @user3151918 Their value. All pointers have fixed size within the program ( and probably the operating system, usually its `sizeof(int)`). And their value is a memory position they point to, in the virtual memory allocated for the running program.

Comment: @luk32 i still dont understand how tht condition works, by comparing size, ur comparing number of characters that each pointer points to? since size of character is 1byte

Comment: @user3151918; Read my answer.

Comment: @user3151918 You need to go over what a pointer is again. You seem to confuse it with something else or misunderstand the concept. There is no size comparison of any kind. You compare only position, not number of characters, nor any kind of size.

Comment: @luk32 since string1 is an array doesnt it always point to position of first element, unless u specify? hence pointer>= string1 ur comparing current position of pointer to first element poistion of string all the time thru the loop?

Comment: @user3151918 yup. Precisely as you said. You can bug you code if you compare "not related" pointers like `pointer2 > string1`. But it still would be comparing position pointed by `pointer2` to the position of 1st element of `string1` just the result might be random, depending where in the memory it will end up.

Comment: @user3151918; `pointer1` is pointing to the last element of array `string1`. By comparing `pointer1 >= string1`, you are checking whether `pointer1` is pointing to the first element or elements before the first one (in reverse order). If it is pointing to the first element, then terminate the loop.

Comment: It can compare the address of the pointer (position). E.g `&string1[1] == string1 + 1` `&string1[1] > string1(string1: &string[0])`

Comment: @haccks `pointer1` changes its value throughout the program. It's kinda vague to say it points to some specified element with out any clarification of what point of code you speak of.

Comment: @luk32; It is obvious that `pointer1` is changing its value throughout the program. I assumed that OP is aware about that.

Comment: @haccks I know, I said it. I am saying you are generally wrong when you say it points to the end of the array, when actually most of the times it does not.

Comment: @luk32; In the beginning of second loop `pointer1` is pointing to the last element of the array `string1`.

Answer (score 0):

The condition in the second loop is wrong. Remember that since you don't initialize `string2` it will contain seemingly random data. Reading that data (like you do in the condition for the second loop) leads to *undefined behavior*.

You have to remember that arrays decays to pointers, so that you can use an array as a pointer, and have e.g. a condition like

```
while (pointer1 >= string1) {...}
```

Comment: i know its wrong , if u had read my question clearly u would have realised that its the only reason i posted the question in the first place -.-

Comment: what exactly r u comparing in that while statement?

Comment: @haccks Care to elaborate why it is wrong? 'cause I'm pretty sure it gives correct results. It might be considered bad habit, and that is IMO very debatable, but I don't think it's wrong.

Comment: @luk32; I think I am wrong in this particular case. It would work. Upvoted to counter wrong vote.

Comment: @user3151918 It's comparing two pointers (like I said, arrays decays to pointers), and loops as long as the pointer `pointer1` is larger or equal to the pointer `string1`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
size_t size = strlen(string1) 
while(size--)
{
    *pointer2 = *pointer1;
    pointer1--;
    pointer2++; 
}
```

Comment: okay so size will keep decrementing and aslong as its not equal to 0 loop will continue is that it/

Comment: @TheBlueCat; Why it should?